# Bar Chart Labels Mystery

Tags: graphics, plotting, labeling

I have some data which I want to plot in a simple bar chart:

```
example = {{"Knowledge", 2}, {"Comprehension", 4}, {"Application", 0}, {"Analysis", 1}, {"Synthesis", 0}, {"Evaluation", 2}}
```

The first element of each pair should be the bar label, and the second should be the height of the bar. I can get the desired result using:

```
BarChart[Last[#] & /@ example, ChartLabels -> {"Knowledge","Comprehension","Application","Analysis","Synthesis","Evaluation"}]
```

[image]

But my real question is this:

Though

```
First[#] &/@ example
```

Returns

```
{"Knowledge", "Comprehension", "Application", "Analysis", "Synthesis", "Evaluation"}
```

When I try:

```
BarChart[Last[#]&/@example, ChartLabels->First[#]&/@example]
```

I get a graph without labels:

[image]

This seems like strange behaviour, can anyone shed some light, or suggest a fix?

Comment: Take a look at what `ChartLabels -> First[#] & /@ example` is doing. You need a bracket around the second part: `ChartLabels -> (First[#] & /@ example)`

Comment: Well, that was easy! Sorry for the wasted time. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Much better: `BarChart[Last /@ example, ChartLabels -> First /@ example]` or `BarChart[example[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> example[[All, 1]]]`.

Comment: That is better, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be careful with passing in arguments to a function when you have a replacement. The problem is currently that:

```
ChartLabels -> First[#] & /@ example
```

is passing the elements of example into all of `ChartLabels -> First[#]` one by one. You need instead to be passing it only into the second argument and so all that is needed to solve the problem is a set of brackets:

```
ChartLabels -> (First[#] & /@ example)
```

Comment: If you take a look at `FullForm[HoldForm[ChartLabels -> First[#] & /@ example]]`, you can instantly see what exactly is going wrong.